# OS X Safari: how do you set the favorite icon in safari for your site?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, safari, osx-yosemite

In OS X Safari, you tap the URL address pane and it will show a window containing the site icons of the sites you added to your favorite folder.
Some sites like `bing.com` is represented by their site icon, some are not.
My site is one of those unfortunate ones.

Currently I'm using this HTML:

```
<link rel="Bookmark" href="../favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" >
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="../favicon57_57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="../favicon114_114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="../favicon72_72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="../favicon144_144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="../favicon60_60.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="../favicon120_120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="../favicon152_152.png" />
```

this works fine for iOS safari and OS X Chrome, but it doesn't work for OS X Safari.
What should I do?

I'm using OS X 10.10 Yosemite and Safari 8.0.6

The icon I'm looking for appears here:
[image]

Comment: Your second line's `rel` attribute should be just `"icon"`. Also, make sure the `favicon.ico` file actually exists at the specified location.

Comment: @StuartWagner I tried and it doesn't work

Comment: Also try removing the first line. If that still doesn't work, move `favicon.ico` into the root of your site. Browsers automatically look for icons there.

Comment: @StuartWagner I've updated my question, I didn't not make the icon that I was looking for clear at the beginning.

Comment: There might be some caching issue. Try it in a different browser.

Comment: @StuartWagner I disabled Safari cache and it still doesn't work